# Empty ng2-select2 value

Tags: angular

How to reset value in `ng2-select2` by click on a button

Currently my **HTML code** is

```
<select2 id="bill" [data]="colBill" [options]="option" (valueChanged)="onBillArray($event);">
```

**Typescript code** is

```
this.arrBill = [];
```

The data is clear in array but it still display in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full example of it:

Template side :

```
<select2 [data]="exampleData" [value]="currentValue" (valueChanged)="valueChanged($event)"></select2>
```

Component side :

```
clearSelection() {
    this.valueChangeValue = '';
    this.exampleData = [];

    // For Multiple true
    // this.currentValue = [];
}
```

Link to the working example [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YWelaW?p=preview)

Comment: @Jim , I have updated the Plnkr , for multiple selection , please have a look

Comment: @Jim, will you please upvote and accept the answer ?

Comment: Hi, I had tried to follow your code to do. The array had been clear but it still display in UI. Do you know what happened to this?

Comment: @Jim, please create Plnkr as I have created, as you can see its working great , there might be spme other issue

Comment: Finally I get it. I make a small mistake on it. Thank you for  your help.